# Second Iteration of 8 Puzzle is Not Working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, puzzle

This is my first time working with Java Swing, so my program is a bit chaotic to say the least. The goal is to have an 8-puzzle take an image, divide it into 9 sectors, then place 8 of them in a specific order (Drop 1 for movement). The program works fine the first time through. Once it is solved it is supposed to randomize the `JButton` components and allow you to solve again.The buttons Randomize, but do not allow me to move them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Normally I would post just the code that I think would have the issue, but due to the chaotic nature of the code, I am posting my entire class.

***EDIT:***
After going through the code line by line, the issue seems to be in the Order() method. If i remove the second "if" statement all together, the program works fine just does not randomize the components. (Same if i use "else" & "else if" for that statement)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JEightPuzzleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
    JButton[][] format = new JButton[3][3];
    JPanel puzzle = new JPanel();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    String path = null;
    int h;
    int w;

    public JEightPuzzleFrame(String Title, String Path) {
        super();
        path = Path;
        add(puzzle);
        makeFrame();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(w + 10, h + 10);
        setTitle(Title);
        setResizable(false);
        jp.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void makeFrame() {
        puzzle.setVisible(true);
        puzzle.setBounds(100, 100, 612, 519);
        makeBtnImg();
        puzzle.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                puzzle.add(format[i][j]);
                if (format[i][j] == buttons[8]) {
                    puzzle.remove(format[i][j]);
                    puzzle.add(jp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void makeBtnImg() {
        try {
            BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            jp.setSize(h, w);
            h = pic.getHeight();
            w = pic.getWidth();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    BufferedImage bimg = pic.getSubimage(i * w / 3, j * h / 3, w / 3, h / 3);
                    if (count < 9) {
                        buttons[count] = new JButton(new ImageIcon(bimg));
                        buttons[count].addActionListener(this);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
            order(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void order(boolean initial) {

        if (initial == true) {
            format[0][0] = buttons[8];
            format[1][0] = buttons[4];
            format[2][0] = buttons[1];

            format[0][1] = buttons[0];
            format[1][1] = buttons[7];
            format[2][1] = buttons[2];

            format[0][2] = buttons[3];
            format[1][2] = buttons[6];
            format[2][2] = buttons[5];
        }
        if (initial == false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    int rd = (int) Math.random() * (9 - 0);
                    JButton temp = buttons[rd];
                    format[i][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        refresh();
    }

    public void refresh() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                puzzle.remove(format[i][j]);
            }
        }
        puzzle.remove(jp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                puzzle.add(format[i][j]);
                if (format[i][j] == buttons[8]) {
                    puzzle.remove(format[i][j]);
                    puzzle.add(jp);
                }
            }
        }
        getContentPane().validate();
        if (format[0][0] == buttons[0] && format[0][1] == buttons[3] && format[0][2] == buttons[6]
                && format[1][0] == buttons[1] && format[1][1] == buttons[4] && format[1][2] == buttons[7]
                && format[2][0] == buttons[2] && format[2][1] == buttons[5] && format[2][2] == buttons[8]) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU WON!");
            order(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton temp;
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Dimension size = button.getSize();

        int buttonX = button.getX();
        int buttonY = button.getY();
        int buttonPosX = buttonX / size.width;
        int buttonPosY = buttonY / size.height;
        int leftNeighbor = buttonPosX - 1;
        int rightNeighbor = buttonPosX + 1;
        int topNeighbor = buttonPosY - 1;
        int bottomNeighbor = buttonPosY + 1;
        int c = 0;

        if (leftNeighbor >= 0 && format[buttonPosY][leftNeighbor] == buttons[8]) {
            c = 1;
        } else if (rightNeighbor < 3 && format[buttonPosY][rightNeighbor] == buttons[8]) {
            c = 2;
        } else if (topNeighbor >= 0 && format[topNeighbor][buttonPosX] == buttons[8]) {
            c = 3;
        } else if (bottomNeighbor <= 2 && format[bottomNeighbor][buttonPosX] == buttons[8]) {
            c = 4;
        } else {
            c = 0;
        }

        switch (c) {

            case 0:
                break;

            case 1:
                temp = format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];
                format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX] = format[buttonPosY][leftNeighbor];
                format[buttonPosY][leftNeighbor] = temp;
                refresh();
                break;

            case 2:
                temp = format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];
                format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX] = format[buttonPosY][rightNeighbor];
                format[buttonPosY][rightNeighbor] = temp;
                refresh();
                break;

            case 3:
                temp = format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];
                format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX] = format[topNeighbor][buttonPosX];
                format[topNeighbor][buttonPosX] = temp;
                refresh();
                break;

            case 4:
                temp = format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];
                format[buttonPosY][buttonPosX] = format[bottomNeighbor][buttonPosX];
                format[bottomNeighbor][buttonPosX] = temp;
                refresh();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Due to the chaotic nature" I know you don't want to take the time to work through it and figure out where the problem is but neither do we. Take a look and see if you can't find some possible spots it could be breaking. Add lots of log statements when you're working on it. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help turning this into a good question.

Comment: I have been working through it line by line and the issue seems to be where I randomize the components. If i remove the code in the else{...} statement in the Order() method it works fine just does not randomize.

Comment: So put that in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this code is hard to read for a few reasons:

1. Variable names are not meaningful. Names like "c" might mean something to you but when others read it we're left to guess at what it might represent.
2. You're using primitives and classes provided by Java even though it would simplify your code to create custom objects of your own design.
3. There are no comments in the code

As for your specific question the problem does indeed lie in the `order` method as you suspected. It's this line:

`int rd = (int) Math.random() * (9 - 0);`

The casting to `int` happens before the multiplication so you're always getting a result of 0 here. This causes all the buttons in your `format` array to be identical.

However, there's a bigger problem. Even if you fix the above line by doing this:

`int rd = (int) (Math.random() * (9 - 0));`

you will still have problems because you never ensure that you only use each button once. In other words, `rd` can be 3 in the current loop and then be 3 again in the next loop because it's random - there is no memory of what has and has not been used before. What you need is a mechanism to prevent duplicates so that each button is unique.

So, something like this should do the trick:

```
if (initial == false) {
            boolean[] isUsed = new boolean[buttons.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    int rd = -1;
                    do{
                        rd = (int) (Math.random() * (9 - 0));
                    }while(isUsed[rd]);
                    isUsed[rd] = true;
                    JButton temp = buttons[rd];
                    format[i][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! For future programs I will be sure to use the tips you suggested. I actually created some logic to prevent duplicates after i posted this. Regarding the randomization, I tried the way you suggested and it still seems to be not functioning correctly. Now there are some movement in the tiles but it is not correct. They seem to randomly swap now as well.

Comment: That's odd, when I try running with the code above it seems to work fine. Are you sure you saw my latest edit?

Comment: I did not see that last edit! This did solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Heathen0042 Thinking about your game some more I'm not sure that randomizing the images in this manner will always be guaranteed to produce a solvable puzzle. I just wanted to mention that you may want to take the time to think about this and as with any code you should thoroughly test it. EDIT: I found [this page](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html) which confirms not all configurations are solvable.

Comment: I appreciate the warning. That is in fact true(not all configurations can be solved), however the constraints of the program do not require me to avoid unsolvable configurations. It may be something extra I do for myself though, because it does not make sense to randomize if the puzzle is unsolvable.

Comment: I understand. This is a great example of how incomplete requirements can lead to undesirable program behavior. Maybe this is part of what you're meant to learn. If you do plan to improve on your program you could also rework it to fit better into the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) as this is a widely used concept in programming.